# Commands that disable everything except the counters

Tags: luatex, tex-core

## what I'm looking for...

I'm looking for a couple a commands,  `\disableAllButCounters` and `\enableAll` that would do the following:

> Everything between `\disableAllButCounters` and
>   `\enableAll`  would be ignored excepted commands such that
>   `\setcounter{counterA}{k}`,  so that the only common thing between
>
> ```
> \disableAllButCounters
> \manyCommands
> \enableAll
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> %\disableAllButCounters
> \manyCommands
> %\enableAll
> ```
>
> would be that after both, the values of the counters is the same. In particular,
>   anything between these commands will not produce any output (nor `aux`).
>
> I'm looking for a solution for latex and for a solution for luatex.

If it exists, these commands could provide a solution to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166427/8323).

## but why!?

Basically, I would like to produce several outputs from a single latex file: one output for the content from A to B, one output for the content from B to C, etc. I plan to do it by cutting the file into multiple files. My question raises the problem of dealing with the references.

If by any chance, you think of a better solution, don't hesitate!!

Comment: Sounds like it might be a job for `\include`, unless you object to its always starting a new page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution takes care of the problem caused by `figure`.

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newcommand{\disableAllButCounters}{%
% Dealing with the figure environment
\LetLtxMacro{\savedfigure}{\figure}
\renewcommand{\figure}{}
\LetLtxMacro{\savedendfigure}{\endfigure}
\renewcommand{\endfigure}{}
% Disabling everything but counter
\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup
}

\newcommand{\enableAllButCounters}{%
% Reenabling everything but counter
\egroup
% Dealing with the figure environment
\renewenvironment{figure}{\savedfigure}{\savedendfigure}
}
```

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem; however, you should put the redefinitions after `\bgroup` so that you don't need to restore anything after `\endgroup`

Comment: @egreg on m'y MWE, it's working. Shall I put \bgroup before or after \egroup?

Comment: With `\caption`? Really?

Comment: @egreg by the way, why do you think it does not solve the problem?

Comment: Haven't tried \caption, but I can add a similar patch for caption. The drawback of this solution is that it is really an ad-hoc solution.

Answer (score 9):

You could try with

```
\newcommand{\disableAllButCounters}{\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup}
\newcommand{\enableAllButCounters}{\egroup}
```

Since `\setcounter` and similar commands act globally, this should do; `\write` commands are executed only when the box eventually finds its way in the main vertical list, which the constructed box won't.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\disableAllButCounters}{\setbox0=\vbox\bgroup}
\newcommand{\enableAllButCounters}{\egroup}

\begin{document}

\section{A}

Text

\disableAllButCounters

\section{B}

Text

\enableAllButCounters

\section{C}

Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the `.aux` file:

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}A}{1}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {3}C}{1}}
```

which shows no entry related to section 2.

Beware that floats could ruin the thing; if you need them, some countermeasures should be taken.

Comment: Very, very sweet answer!

Comment: \begin{figure}...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There are other things that could go wrong. But without information about what the OP is expecting there, it would be a waste of time trying to catch all exceptions.

Comment: @egreg yes I'm just miffed that I decided not to post that as I didn't know if it was worth disabling floats, and then you posted it anyway and will no doubt get the 15pts:-)

Comment: Hi @egreg and @DavidCarlisle. I am far too ignorant to understand your answer (@egreg) and why `floats` could create problems. But I think I might use `floats`: I'm not using `figure` but using `mdframed` environments. If one of you could elaborate on these `floats`, it could be useful. Thanks! ... and I might use also `figure`!

Comment: see edit on why I'm looking for such commands.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and @egreg I have found a solution for the `figure` environment. Shall I post it or shall I propose an edit of @egreg's answer? Actually, I see my answer more as a proposal to you than a definitive answer.