# How to store the definition of a command? Or, how to disable locally a command?

Tags: macros, tex-core

### what?

I would like to "store" the definition of `\includegraphics` into `\something` so that the following logics will work:

```
% the following line is what I am looking for
store(\includegraphics, \something)
% and then I want to achieve what follows

\renewcommand\includegraphics}[2][]
{}

\doalotofstuff

\renewcommand\includegraphics}[2][]
{%
get_the_definition_from(\something)
}

% now I can again use \includegraphics with its usual definition
```

Is it possible and easily achievable?

### but why?!

I want to disable the command `\includegraphics` in some parts on my document and be able to get again the usual `\includegraphics` after. This question is related to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166510/8323) (the solution does not work if the `\includegraphics` command is active.

Comment: To store it: `\let\savedincludegraphics\includegraphics` and then to restore it `\let\includegraphics\savedincludegraphics`

Comment: Can we assume the local 'place' can form a group (defined scope, not definitions need to 'escape')?

Comment: @JosephWright I don't understand all the terms of your question, but I think, more or less: YES.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
```

and

```
\LetLtxMacro\colassavedincludegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{}
```

for disabling the command; for reenabling it

```
\LetLtxMacro\includegraphics\colassavedincludegraphics
```

For the specific command `\let` might be sufficient, but `\LetLtxMacro` is safer for commands that accept optional arguments.

See [When to use \LetLtxMacro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88001/when-to-use-letltxmacro) for more information about `\LetLtxMacro`.

For environments it depends on how they are defined, but the `comment` package may reveal useful.

Comment: Thanks! I have asked another question for `environements`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166724/8323

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are looking for `\let`:

```
\let\something=\includegraphics
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same with environments???

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166724/8323