# How to store the definition of an environment? Or, how to disable locally an environment?

Tags: environments

### what?

I would like to "store" the definition of the environment `figure` into `\something` so that the following logics will work:

```
% the following line is what I am looking for
store(figure, \something)
% and then I want to achieve what follows

\renewenvironment{figure}{}{}
{}

\doalotofstuff

\renewenvironment{figure}
{get_the_initial_definition_from(\something)}
{get_the_final_definition_from(\something)}

% now I can again use \begin{figure}...\end{figure} with its usual definition
```

Is it possible and easily achievable?

### but why?!

I want to disable the environment `figure` in some parts on my document and be able to get again theenvironment `figure` after. This question is related to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166510/8323) (the solution does not work if the environment `figure` is active).

Comment: You're taking the wrong approach, in my opinion. However, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159820/comment-sty-and-utf8-encoding

Comment: I have no knowledge of `tex`... so, in a way, this is the only approach I can imagine!

Comment: You want to postprocess the PDF file. If all sections start a new page, just remove the pages you don't want. If sections don't start a new page, what you want to do has little sense.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116670/duplicating-environments

Comment: The `comment` package does not increment the values of the counters. Your approach is interesting. My problem is quite complicated actually. The length of the pages of `part(i)` depends on the length of the last page of `part(i-1)`, where the length of the last page is what you can imagine...